# Dropzone.js and dropbox API

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I am implementing in my system dropzone.js to upload files to the server or to dropbox depending on the size of the file.

And i also use sweet alerts for notifications.

When the file is uploaded to my server **dropzone** **works correctly** but when it is uploaded to **dropbox  does not return any results**

**test with files larger than 6 Mb**

[Demo here](http://test.dedragon.net/)

and them the loading bar does not work properly

[Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)

HTML:

```html
<form id="cuadro" action="" class="dropzone">

</form>
<p id="texto_carga" style="color: #009688; display:none">Espera mientras se procesa el archivo...</p>
```

JS:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     var errors = false;
     var Dropzone = new Dropzone("#cuadro", {
     url: "../utilidades/pruebasupload.php?id=<?=$personaId?>&codigo=<?=$codigo?>",
     acceptedFiles: ".EDF,.edf,.pdf,.PDF,.rar,.RAR,.jpg,.png,.gif",
     maxFiles: 1,
     error:function(){
       errors = true;
     },
     processing:function(){ 
        $('#texto_carga').show();
     },
     complete:function(){
        if(errors){
          swal({
             title: 'Error al cargar el achivo!',
             text: 'Ha ocurrido un error al intentar cargar el archivo. Póngase en contacto con el administrador del sistema',
             type: 'error',
             icon: 'error'
          });
          $('#texto_carga').hide();
        }else{
          swal({
             title: 'Carga completa!',
             text: 'Hemos cargado el archivo de la prueba exitosamente',
             type: 'success',
             icon: 'success'
          });  
          $('#texto_carga').hide();
        }
      }
   });
</script>
```

PHP pruebasupload.php

```html
require_once "../terceros/dropbox/vendor/autoload.php";
require_once '../clases/servidor_archivos_controller.php';
require_once '../clases/conexion.php';

use Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxFile;

$conexion = new conexion;
$_servidor = new servidorArchivos;

$data = $_servidor->buscarConexion();
$dropboxKey = "";
$dropboxSecret = "";
$acessToken = "";
$appName= "";
$megas = "";

if(empty($data)){
    $megas = 200000;
}else{
    $dropboxKey = $data[0]['Keyapp'];
    $dropboxSecret = $data[0]['Secret'];
    $acessToken = $data[0]['Token'];
    $appName= $data[0]['Appname'];
    $megas = $data[0]['Megas'];
    $megas = ($megas * 1024) * 1024 ;
}
 
 
 
 
if($tama[0]>$megas){
    try{
     //upload file to dropbox
     $file = $dropbox->simpleUpload($tempFile,$nombredropbox, ['autorename' => true]);  
     //share a file
     $response = $dropbox->postToAPI("/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings", ["path" => $nombredropbox, "settings" => ['requested_visibility' => 'public']]);
    $data = $response->getDecodedBody();
    $link = $data['url'];
    //save link to document in to DB
    $query = "insert into pruebas_archivos (Codigo,Archivo,Ubicacion)values('$savecodge','$nombredropbox','2')";
                $datos=  $conexion->NonQuery($query); 
                http_response_code(200);
             }catch(\EXCEPTION $e){
                ERROR('001',$E);
                http_response_code(400);
             }
        }else{
            $targetPath = "../public/pruebas/";  
            $targetFile =  $targetPath.$id ."_". $nombreCompleto;  //5
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            //save the url into DB
            $query = "insert into pruebas_archivos (Codigo,Archivo,Ubicacion)values('$savecodge','$nombreCompleto','1')";
            $conexion->NonQuery($query); 
            http_response_code(200); 
      
        }
}        
        
    function error($numero,$texto){
    $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
    fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."] Error $numero: $texto\r\n");
    fclose($ddf);
  }
```

PHP init file
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly does “not return any results”? Your PHP script only seems to respond with either a status code 200, or a 400 in case of an error. What “results” are you expecting to appear where exactly now?

Comment: I need the system to return 200 if it has uploaded the file or 400 if it has not. but 
sometimes the file has been loaded correctly but does not return any results

Comment: Meaning what, exactly? Does the client-side part just ”hang”, and not go into the `complete`handler at all? Something else? What are you observing in the browser dev tools network panel?

Comment: I have prepared a demo for you. you will find it in the text of the question

Comment: Have you checked the `post_max_size` and  `upload_file_maxsize` directives on php.ini? [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/7302869)

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo yes i have,

`allow_url_fopen On
display_errors Off
error_reporting E_ALL
file_uploads On
include_path .:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear
log_errors On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value
max_execution_time 10800
max_input_time 10800
memory_limit 128M
open_basedir no value
post_max_size 128M
session.save_path /opt/alt/php72/var/lib/php/session
short_open_tag On
upload_max_filesize 1G`

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo But that's not the problem. That works correctly. the problem occurs when I try to upload the file to dropbox

Comment: I just tried to upload a file using your demo, and the script died exactly at 30s. Are you using FastCGI? Perhaps the idle_timeout is set to 30s

Comment: I'm not using FastCGI, in fact I've never heard it before. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your demo, and was able to upload a bigger than 6mb file now and then.
Sometimes, while doing the upload, the script died exactly at 30s.

Thus, it seems that the logic of your code is ok, but there is some timeout occurring in your server. As you already pointed, the `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` seems to be properly set (I'd double check with `phpinfo();`), but depending on the server you are running, you might have another places to check.

- If it is running on Apache, check in the `httpd.conf` the `TimeOut` directive.
- If you are using `php-fpm`, check in the `www.conf` the `request_terminate_timeout` directive.
- If you are using nginx, check the `fastcgi_read_timeout` directive

[reference](https://www.fdgweb.com/increase-php-timeout-values-apache-ngnix/)

Comment: have shared screenshots of the files

Comment: First of all, create a `phpinfo.php` file with `<?php phpinfo();` and check the output on the browser. If the values are different from your print, you must find the proper `php.ini` to edit. If they are equal, you must find the config in the server instead (not on php, but probably apache)